# Enroll student in a course in moodle outside moodle 1.9 platform?

Tags: mysql, moodle

I'm making my own form to enroll students in a moodle course. I have this on another server, I know the functions within **moodle** that lets me do that but I want to know how can I enroll a student in a course using just **mysql**?

I know that that table `mdl_role_assignning` is where I record the user type, in this case a student, but I see that it points to a `contextid` which is where I get lost. I know that its a column in the table `mdl_context` but where's the `courseid` indicating that user is a student?

Comment: Moodle 1.9 hasn't been updated for 3 years, you would be far better off upgrading then using web services to enrol a student. https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/How_to_create_and_enable_a_web_service The upgrade route is upgrade to the latest version of 1.9, then upgrade to 2.2 then upgrade to either 2.6 or 2.7.https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Upgrading_to_Moodle_2.2 then https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Upgrade

Comment: I know its really old but its what my company is working with and my superior doesn't take any advice from me...thanks for your answer anyways